# Strange Error with Push Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I just created a calculator app with storyboards using two views. I started my simulator, and everything worked fine at first. On the first screen, I was able to use the "Calculator" button to switch to the second screen, and on the second screen I had a button to go back to the main menu. But when I switched from the main menu back to the calculator a second time, the app crashed, and the following error occurred:

> 2013-02-21 20:55:36.556 CTS Calculator[22637:c07] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not
>   find a navigation controller for segue 'To Calculator'. Push segues
>   can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance
>   of UINavigationController.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x15a9012 0x12b6e7e 0x650f31 0x642b99 0x642c14 0x12ca705 0x1fe2c0 0x1fe258 0x2bf021 0x2bf57f 0x2be6e8
>   0x22dcef 0x22df02 0x20bd4a 0x1fd698 0x260bdf9 0x260bad0 0x151ebf5
>   0x151e962 0x154fbb6 0x154ef44 0x154ee1b 0x260a7e3 0x260a668 0x1faffc
>   0x1ecd 0x1df5) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

I am not sure why this did not happen the first time I pushed the calculator button. I have a custom segue transition going back to the menu, but not from the menu to the calculator. My navigation controller is set up fine, I believe. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Error shows you dont have a navigation controller. and you are setting segue style to push. Change the segue style to modal and give a try

Comment: Thanks, it worked... why does this happen? Shouldn't I be able to use a "push" animation?

Answer (score 4):

Error shows you dont have a navigation controller. and you are setting segue style to push. Change the segue style to modal and give a try.
Yes. You can use `push` then the root view controller should be a navigation controller. 
Check these links
[Adding a Navigation Controller to a Storyboard](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/9781449321123/4dot-storyboards/id3077160)
[Use Storyboards to Build Navigation Controller and Table View](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

Comment: I have this exact same problem, and I've changed to a MODAL SEGUE, but my storyboard is not updating either. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949638/push-segue-error-even-i-used-modal-segue)