# performSegueWithIdentifier error

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Updated:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addMapItem" {
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(textAddress.text, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? MKPlacemark {
                var lat = placemark.coordinate.latitude
                var long = placemark.coordinate.longitude
                var coordinates = placemark.coordinate
                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = self.textName.text
                annotation.subtitle = self.textAddress.text
                self.annotations.append(annotation)
                var destination : FirstViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FirstViewController
                destination.savedItems = self.annotations
            }
        })
    }
}
```

On my AddLocation view controller, I have 2 segues. One that is triggered by the button being pressed, which takes the data entered and adds it to a table. Another segue (the one we are currently working on) takes the data, converts the address to an annotation, and then passes that annotation to a variable on my map view controller and adds the annotation.

[image]

Comment: try setting your sender to **nil** once

Comment: @DanBeaulieu that doesn't make any changes to my errors.

Comment: You said in your description: `performSegueWithIdentifier("addMapItem", sender: self)` but in your code it says `performSegueWithIdentifier("addMapItem", sender: UIButton.self)`? Change it to `sender: sender` and that should solve the first problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `UIButton.self` as sender, use `sender`. And you can't use a closure with `performSegueWithIdentifier`:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("addMapItem", sender: UIButton.self) {
    // Some code
}
```

use:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("addMapItem", sender: sender)
```

and my guess is you forgot to add `self` in this line:

```
destination.savedItems = annotations    // Should be self.annotations
```

This is where the code should be put so it will be called when you use `performSegueWithIdentifier`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addMapItem" {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting both errors with that code, actually.

Comment: Just woke up, so I might be off. I see you're having a closure behind `performSegueWithIdentifier`. That might cause it.

Comment: That does fix the error, but I was wanting it to perform all the code within that closure after `performSegueWithIdentifier`. The only reason I was using `performSegueWithIdentifier` is to pass the annotations array to the view controller with a map.

Comment: Thats not the place to put the code. I'll show you where. Gimme a sec

Comment: Gave me an error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'addMapItem'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
`. Sorry for my inexperience, not exactly sure what this means. The view controller I'm sending the data from already has a segue to my second view controller, but I'm also wanting it to send data to my third while opening the second view.

Comment: It says its looking for a `UINavigationController`. I'm not sure what you did there.. Can you show me the `prepareForSegue` code and how and where did you add the segue identifier "addMapItem"?

Comment: You said you have two ways of changing the views. How is the other one changing to another view? According to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017191/strange-error-with-push-segue) "Error shows you dont have a navigation controller. and you are setting segue style to push."

Comment: How can I set the segue to where it will just pass the data and not actually show the view controller? Or would it make more sense to just create a public variable in another file and upon clicking the button, it adds the annotation to the public variable, then my map view controller shows that annotation?

Comment: Hmm, the whole point of a segue is to transition to a that view. You could create a global, but I'm personally not a huge fan of it. You can create an instance of the view controller and pass the data to it, but that would be no different than a simple class so theres no need to have the view controller then? As it is now, I don't really understand what you're exactly trying to do. The last error you got has something to do with the way you've set up the segue's.

Comment: As I said, I'm not too experienced with Swift or iOS in general, so I have no idea how to create an instance of the view controller. I'm thinking it could be easier to just have a public array where every time you add a location, it adds the annotation to the public array, then on my map view, it automatically displays the array of saved annotations when the app loads.

Comment: Yea you could try that. If you need help with the segue problem I can try to help more, but need a bit more information. Everything is a bit too vague right now :)

Comment: Well since I don't need to transition between views, I guess I don't need any more help with the segue. I thought I could make another segue that would solely pass the variable between views, not change views as well. But thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: No problem. Just one last question. So those views already exists? Then theres indeed no need to use a segue. Instead you can try to find the instance and pass it there.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm not sure what you mean by finding an instance. All I want to do is when the IBAction button is pressed, it passes the variable into an array on my main view controller.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Are you using a navigation controller? Else you can use a delegate to pass back the data.

Comment: I think I've got it figured out. I created a task manager swift  file, which has a struct and function. When the button is pressed, it appends the annotation to the variable in the task manager. Then I access the variable from my map view to add the annotation. The only problem I am left with is updating the map view when the annotation is added while the app is running so that it will show after it's been added in the other view.

Comment: Well, a delegate would be quite useful for that, but thats another question and too much to discuss using comments. I can show you a post of my earlier answer to someone else: [press me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934078/passing-data-between-views-in-one-viewcontroller-in-swift/29934291#29934291) and read the delegate section.